# Adding older dates to fiscal calendar and following a pattern

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a fiscal calendar table for different IDs (sample below). Some IDs start their fiscal year in January, others start in another month.
I also have other columns (not all columns included in the sample) for which the start and end date differs depending on the ID, like week_of_year depends on date
when the fiscal year starts, not necessary beginning of the year (January 01). Most of the IDs follow 4-4-5 or 4-5-4 fiscal calendar so in week_of_period we get the number of the week in the given 4-4-5 period.

| ID | date | month | week_of_year | week_of_period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-01-29 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2017-01-30 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2017-01-31 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2017-02-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2017-02-02 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-10-08 | 3 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-10-09 | 3 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-10-10 | 3 | 11 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-10-11 | 3 | 11 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-10-12 | 3 | 11 | 2 |
| 3 | 2022-02-26 | 8 | 35 | 4 |
| 3 | 2022-02-27 | 8 | 35 | 4 |
| 3 | 2022-02-28 | 9 | 36 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-02-29 | 9 | 36 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-02-20 | 9 | 36 | 1 |

As shown in the example the first date for each ID is different, what I would like to get is a fiscal calendar for every ID that starts on 01/01/2015. I'd like to add the missing dates and follow the patterns for each ID for other columns, there are too many IDs and data in my current table for me to manually hard code the month, week of period, week of year and other columns I have in the table. Is there a way to add the old dates and have them follow the same pattern for each ID?